# Docker container run with error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, spring, docker

I am doing build images:

```
docker build -t jkh9 .
```

and running container:

```
docker run jkh9
```

and get exception:

```
C:\Users\kulik\IdeaProjects\JkhPaymentTemplateService>docker run jkh9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

this project success start from command line

`java -jar target\JkhPaymentTemplateService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

My DockerFile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
ENV DB_HOST localhost
ENV DB_PORT 2376
COPY pom.xml /pom.xml
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean
RUN mvn -f pom.xml install
RUN mvn -f pom.xml package
RUN mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

FROM openjdk:11.0-jdk
COPY --from=build /target/JkhPaymentTemplateService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar JkhPaymentTemplateService.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/JkhPaymentTemplateService.jar"]
CMD java -classpath JkhPaymentTemplateService
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JkhPaymentTemplateService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate.JkhPaymentTemplateService</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>

                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate.JkhPaymentTemplateService</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <build>
                                <entryPoint>
                                    java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -cp
                                    '/maven/*' play.core.server.ProdServerStart
                                </entryPoint>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This project is

and i get error.
What should I change in pom or dockerfile?
IDE - Intellage idea.

UPD:
I am change pom.xml, but but the error remained

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Remove the assembly plugin and the docker plugin. As you are using Spring BOot 2.3 that can out-of-the-box build a docker container. Run `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image` and remove your `Dockerfile` as well as you won't need it.

Comment: I also doubt that `ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate` is your main class, it rather looks like only a package. Finally the jar already automatically starts the application so not sure why you run a jar and a java cmd.

Comment: I think the problem with his `Dockerfile` is that he only copies the `pom.xml` into the image and not the actual sources.

Comment: @M.Deinum i am use OS Windows, 'spring-boot:build-image' doesn't work there. 'ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate' it is my package. I am tried '<mainClass>ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate.JkhPaymentTemplateService</mainClass>' too, but result was the same.

Comment: Your dockerfile is weird as well as mentioned before. especially the entrypoint and cmd it doesn't make sense. Your `pom.xml` as well, as you are using docker multistage builds you should be able to invoke the `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image` from within your build container. In any case calling `mvn install` and then `mvn package` doesn't make sense it will build the application twice.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you only need this configuratin of your `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am change my pom, updated images, run container and get error too. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.kulikovskiy.jkh.jkhpaymenttemplate.....

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:
I am delete plugin io.fabric8 from pom.xml, and modify DockerFile.
After i am ran command docker build -t <name_container> .  That is all.

Correct DockerFile:

FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY src /home/app/src

COPY pom.xml /home/app

RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

COPY --from=build /home/app/target/JkhPaymentTemplateService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/usr/local/lib/JkhPaymentTemplateService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 8081

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/JkhPaymentTemplateService-1.0-
SNAPSHOT.jar"]